# 2D arrays not saving value

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I apologize for asking help with homework assignment...but I am stuck.  Assignment is 2D arrays in a TicTacToe java program.
My methods moveHuman and moveAI were void, but it wasn't saving the value for the progression of the game.  So I changed it to a char[][] method, but that has caused the program to hang after the moveHuman method is called.  I know this because I have put in all sorts of print statements so I know where my program is in the progression of things and it prints "moveHuman" and it doesn't even prompt me for entry of where I want to move.  If you want to help me fix this, it is due tonight by midnight.  Great Friday evening activity!  Thanks!!

```
//  File: TicTacToe.java
//**************************************************************************

import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class jkcrosby_TicTacToe

{ 
private static Scanner get;
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
get = new Scanner ( System.in );
char[][] board = new char[ 3 ][ 3 ];

// Initialize the board to all spaces
for (int r=0; r<board.length; r++){
  for(int c=0; c<board[r].length; c++){
  board[r][c]= ' ';
  }
}
// Print the game board
   printBoard(board);
// Keep playing while the game isn't finished
   while (checkWinner(board) =='N'){
// Have the human player make a move 
   moveHuman(board);
// Print the board after the user plays
   printBoard(board);
// Check to see if the game is finished ('X' wins or 
// it is a tie). If it is, break out of the loop. 
   if (checkWinner(board) == 'X' || checkWinner(board) == 'O' || checkWinner(board) == 'T')
   break;
// Have the AI make a move
   moveAI(board);
// Print the board after the AI plays
   printBoard(board);
// Check to see who the winner is checkWinner(board);
   } 
// If the winner is 'X' or 'O', print that, otherwise, it is a tie
   char win=checkWinner(board);
   switch (win) {
   case 'X': case 'O': System.out.printf("%c wins!\n", win);
          break;
   case 'T': System.out.printf("It is a tie!\n");
          break;
   }
   }// end of main method

   /**
    * Validate a move for the human player
    *
    * @param board The game board
    */
    public static void moveHuman ( char[][] board )
    {
    get= new Scanner (System.in);
    int r;
    int c;
    System.out.println("X's turn!\r\n");
    // Get the location from the user and validate it (within bounds
    do{
      System.out.println("Enter the row and column, separated by spaces: ");
      r=get.nextInt();
      c=get.nextInt();
    }while((r<0 || r>2 ||c<0||c>2)|| board[r][c] !=' '|| board[r][c]=='\u0000' ); // and is already occupied).
   // Mark the position in the board with an 'X' according to the user's
   // specified location
      board[r][c]='X';
   //return board[r][c];
 } //end method moveHuman

/** 
 * Makes a move for the AI, and marks the board with an 'O'.
 *
 * @param board The game board
 */ public static void moveAI ( char[][] board )
{
// Check that the random location generated is valid.
// Keep recalculating the location if the one generated is
// already occupied.
   get = new Scanner (System.in);
   int r;
   int c;
   Random rand = new Random();
   System.out.println("O's turn!");
   do{
      System.out.println("Enter the row and column, separated by spaces: ");
      r = rand.nextInt(3);
      c = rand.nextInt(3);
   } while((r<0|| r>2|| c<0||c>2) || board[r][c]!=' '|| board[r][c]=='\u0000');
      board[r][c]='O';
// Be sure to mark the valid position in the board with an 'O'
}


/* ******************************************************************* *
 * ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE DOES NOT NEED TO BE MODIFIED BY YOU.  YOU  *
 * CAN CERTAINLY LOOK AT THE CODE, THOUGH, TO SEE WHAT'S HAPPENING.    *
 * IN FACT, YOU'RE ENCOURAGED TO LOOK AT THIS CODE AT SOME POINT.      *
 * ******************************************************************* */


/**
 * Prints out the tic-tac-toe board
 *
 * @param   board   The game board
 */
public static void printBoard ( char[][] board )
{
    // Box drawing unicode characters:

    char a = '\u250c';              // U+250C : top-left
    char b = '\u2510';              // U+2510 : top-right
    char c = '\u2514';              // U+2514 : bottom-left
    char d = '\u2518';              // U+2518 : bottom-right
    char e = '\u252c';              // U+252C : top-vertical-connector
    char f = '\u2534';              // U+2534 : bottom-vertical-connector
    char g = '\u251c';              // U+251C : left-horizontal-connector
    char h = '\u2524';              // U+2524 : right-horizontal-connector
    char i = '\u253c';              // U+253C : center plus sign connector
    char j = '\u2500';              // U+2500 : horizontal
    char k = '\u2502';              // U+2502 : vertical
    String l = j + "" + j + "" + j; // Three horizontals
    // Print out the game board

    System.out.printf ( "\n    0   1   2\n" +
            "  %c%s%c%s%c%s%c\n" +
            "0 %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n" +
            "  %c%s%c%s%c%s%c\n" +
            "1 %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n" +
            "  %c%s%c%s%c%s%c\n" +
            "2 %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n" +
            "  %c%s%c%s%c%s%c\n\n",
            a, l, e, l, e, l, b,
            k, board[0][0], k, board[0][1], k, board[0][2], k,
            g, l, i, l, i, l, h,
            k, board[1][0], k, board[1][1], k, board[1][2], k,
            g, l, i, l, i, l, h,
            k, board[2][0], k, board[2][1], k, board[2][2], k,
            c, l, f, l, f, l, d );

}          

/**
 * Checks the result of the game
 *
 * @param   board   The game board
 * @return          'X' if 'X' is the winner
 *                  'O' if 'O' is the winner
 *                  'T' if the game is a tie
 *                  'N' if the game isn't finished
 */
public static char checkWinner( char[][] board )
{
    if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[0][1] == 'X' && board[0][2] == 'X' ||       // Check row 0
            board[1][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X' ||   // Check row 1
            board[2][0] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X' ||   // Check row 2
            board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][0] == 'X' && board[2][0] == 'X' ||   // Check col 0
            board[0][1] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X' ||   // Check col 1
            board[0][2] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X' ||   // Check col 2
            board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X' ||   // Check diag \
            board[0][2] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][0] == 'X')      // Check diag /
    {
        return 'X';
    }
    else if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[0][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O' ||  // Check row 0
            board[1][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' ||   // Check row 1
            board[2][0] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O' ||   // Check row 2
            board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][0] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O' ||   // Check col 0
            board[0][1] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' ||   // Check col 1
            board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O' ||   // Check col 2
            board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O' ||   // Check diag \
            board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O')      // Check diag /
    {
        return 'O';
    }  

    boolean finished = true;

    // If there is a blank space in the board, the game isn't finished yet
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < board[ i ].length; j++)
            if (board[ i ][ j ] == ' ')
                finished = false;

    // If the board is finished and 'X' or 'O' wasn't returned, then it is a tie
    // Otherwise, the game is not finished yet
    if ( finished == true )
        return 'T';
    else
        return 'N';
}
```

}

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I would also add that your deadline is not part of the question.  If you have a genuine reason, ask for an extension.  Otherwise, your deadline is not our concern.

Comment: Actually @Stephen C, the deadline was relative, to reflect urgency.  I'm glad you edited the rude comment that you wrote...twice  You should have edited it further.  No extensions allowed.   No I didn't make the deadline, but my program works. :)  Thanks for your concern!  I'm glad there's such kind and considerate people like you in this community.

Comment: On the subject of "urgency", I suggest you read this:  [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569).

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your move validation.

In `moveHuman` you should be checking `|| board[r][c] != ' '` (i.e. the loop should continue if the move chosen *is not* an empty square).

Similarly, in `moveAI`:

```
do {
    // Note the bound is *exclusive* - it should be 3 to get 
    // values in the range 0-2
    r = rand.nextInt(3); 
    c = rand.nextInt(3);
} while (board[r][c] != ' ');
```

Comment: Yes, I had 
` while (board[r][c] == ' ');`
originally, but it didn't make sense. because
 ` do{...
    }while((r<0 || r>2 || c<0 || c>2)&& board[r][c] == ' ');`

Comment: You've tested all the code and gotten the tic-tac-toe to work? 
OK...I will take your word for it with == and changed it back to that...  but why would moveHuman err out on me.  I changed the method from public static void to public static char[ ][ ] and returns  board[r][c] because it wasn't "saving" the move.  Eclipse and vim both don't like that it is char[ ][ ].  Any thoughts?
`public static char[][] moveHuman ( char[][] board )
    {  ......
            return board[r][c];
            } `

Comment: You don't need to return the board. Changing the value will "save" it in the array you created in `main`.

Comment: If you did want to return the board, you'd have to use `return board;`, not `return board[r][c];`. The error is because you're attempting to return a char from the board, not the array itself.

Comment: Thanks @teppic!  I fixed, my program.  The != was correct after all.  If you're interested, I fixed the code above to reflect my changes.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my code in my question to reflect the correct changes and code that compiles.
In particular:

moveHuman and moveAI needed:

`}while((r<0 || r>2 ||c<0||c>2)|| board[r][c] !=' '|| board[r][c]=='\u0000' );`

moveAI needed:

`r = rand.nextInt(3);
  c = rand.nextInt(3);`

instead of something fancy I was trying to do that gave me an infinite loop.

And my moveHuman and moveAI methods were reverted back to static void methods for simplicity.